# Правильный запрос в БД

Tags: запрос, mysql

Здравствуйте, есть таблица в которой 5 столбиков:

```
id    id_produkt    id_storage    id_place    quant
1         1             1            1          5
2         1             1            2          1
3         1             1            3          2
4         1             2            1          2
5         1             2            2          10
```

Данная таблица показывает остаток на складе по складам и зонам. Представим, что нам нужно списать 16 штук товаров. Как сделать так чтобы началось списываться со склада 1 и зоны 1, потом со склада 1 зона 2, как только зоны закончатся, списываем со следующего склада, в итоге должна получиться такая таблица:

```
id    id_produkt    id_storage    id_place    quant
 1         1             1            1          0
 2         1             1            2          0
 3         1             1            3          0
 4         1             2            1          0
 5         1             2            2          4
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что эта задача должна решаться именно средствами БД?

Comment: не уверен, подскажите правильное направление, пожалуйста

Comment: хранить остатки вообще порочная идея. потом захотите возврат оформить вот намаетесь обратно все возвращать... про бизнес-логику согласен с @Fike.

Comment: Возврат можно делать на 1 склад а потом перемешением перекинуть на разные

Comment: @benjibboy, да, но это только начало. дальше будет хуже.  
правильно хранить движения, а не остатки. и ваш вопрос сводится к тому, чтобы получить аккумулированные остатки по складам и списать их в порядке согласно учетной политике, а не по id и точно не sql'ем это делается. хотя у вас тут только количества, значит до сумм еще не дошли, все впереди :)  
циклом, циклом это все делать надо.

Answer (score 1):

[@benjibboy](/users/16468/benjibboy), я не спец по БД, но мне кажется, что этим должно заниматься приложение, которое взаимодействует с БД, обычно БД - это именно хранилище, а вся бизнес-логика выносится в приложение. Хотя в БД есть хранимые процедуры и через них наверняка будет быстрее работать.